# How to pass variable from server to ui and display in shiny template?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to read a value from a dataframe which will eventually be updated every 2 minutes.  For now I am struggling on getting the data to the UI in shiny via htmltemplate.

I've tried various implementations of render and outputUI but can't seem to figure it out.

```
library(shiny)

test_date <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'))
score <- c(75,80,85,90)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(test_date, score)

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="color:red">{{outputUI("score_value")}}</p>
  </body>
  </html>'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$score_value <- renderUI(
    {mean(my_dataframe$score)}
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What i would like to see is the mean of these 4 numbers rendered in the UI.

The current code puts my object into a div and it's not what i'm looking for

```
  <html>
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="color:red">
<div id="score_value" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what's this one expected to do `outputUI("score_value")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First main thing that your code misses is `{{headContent()}}`

```
library(shiny)

test_date <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'))
score <- c(75,80,85,90)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(test_date, score)

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  {{headContent()}}
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="color:red">{{textOutput("score_value")}}</div>
  </body>
  </html>'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$score_value <- renderText(
    {mean(my_dataframe$score)}
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Next, because you are just rendering a text value use `renderText` and `textOutput` . It works fine then.

Based on the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html),

> headContent() must be placed in the `<head>` section of the HTML, if
>   this is a complete HTML page (as opposed to a component of a page,
>   which we’ll discuss later). This tells Shiny that the various Shiny
>   header code should be included here.

Also, the `p` tag is replaced with `div` tag for the style to reflect.

Comment: I selected this as the answer because it wasn't the variations of render that was causing me to mishap but it was the headcontent piece that i was missing.  Appreciate the direction and supporting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First the code, does not run on my machine, just grey page ... strange.

Second outputUI is not a valid function, which shiny version are you using? 
I use:

`uiOutput()`

Third, your output looks correct I think, you have tell renderUI what it should contain (a render element) e.g.

`renderUI({
  tagList( 
    renderText(
      mean( my_dataframe$score)
    )
  )
})`

EDIT: 
some dependencies where missing. Here the fully working code with some dependencies added:

```
library(shiny)

test_date <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'))
score <- c(75,80,85,90)
my_dataframe <- data.frame(test_date, score)

ui <- htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '

    <html>
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  
    <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>  
    <script type="application/html-dependencies">
    json2[2014.02.04];
  jquery[1.11.3];
  shiny[0.13];
  ionrangeslider[2.0.12];
  strftime[0.9.2]
  </script>
    <script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
    <link href="shared/ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="shared/ionrangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinShiny.css" 
  rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="shared/ionrangeslider/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="shared/strftime/strftime-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p style="color:red">{{ uiOutput("score_value") }}</p>
    </body>
    </html>
'
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$score_value <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      renderText(
        mean(my_dataframe$score)
      )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test right now but have you tried wrapping htmltemplate in a shinyui function like so?

```
ui <- shinyUI(htmlTemplate(
  text_ = '
  <html>
  <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html- dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0]</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p style="color:red">{{renderUI("score_value")}}</p>
  </body>
  </html>'
))
```

Comment: I have and it doesn't produce a separate result.  Thanks for the thought and contribution though.